# Replace default value with another default value Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code which works fine

```
replacePointsWithZeros :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replacePointsWithZeros _ _ [] = []
replacePointsWithZeros replacee replacer (x:xs)
   | replacee == x = replacer:replacePointsWithZeros replacee replacer xs
   | otherwise = x:replacePointsWithZeros replacee replacer xs
```

but i want to replace the replacee and replacer arguments with default values, so essentially what i want is

```
replacePointsWithZeros :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
replacePointsWithZeros [] = []
replacePointsWithZeros (x:xs)
   | '.' == x = '0':replacePointsWithZeros xs
   | otherwise = x:replacePointsWithZeros xs
```

However when I try that it complains about the types with a message I dont really understand as I am very new to Haskell. What am I doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Im assuming the issue is in the line

```
replacePointsWithZeros :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

and the fact that im using a instead of Char but if I switch a to Char I get an issue with the Eq statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you write `'.' == x`, this means that `x` is a `Char`, and therefore `(x:xs)` is a list of `Char`s, so a `[Char]`, or a `String`.

Furthermore you write `'0':` and `x:` as output, hence that means that the output is a list of `Char`s as well. This thus means that the signature of `replacePointsWithZeros` is:

```
replacePointsWithZeros :: String -> String
replacePointsWithZeros [] = []
replacePointsWithZeros (x:xs)
   | '.' == x = '0':replacePointsWithZeros xs
   | otherwise = x:replacePointsWithZeros xs
```

You can make the above more lazy by putting the condition in a mapping function:

```
replacePointsWithZeros :: String -> String
replacePointsWithZeros [] = []
replacePointsWithZeros (x:xs) = f x : replacePointsWithZeros xs
    where f '.' = '0'
          f x = x
```

and we can use a `map` function instead of the explicit recursion:

```
replacePointsWithZeros :: String -> String
replacePointsWithZeros = map f
    where f '.' = '0'
          f x = x
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked just fine. Do I have to use ```Eq``` only if i use flexible types that are to be compared?

Comment: @CalleAhlgren `func :: [a] -> [a]` says that `func` can be used with *any* choice of type for `a` (e.g. `[Int] -> [Int]`, `[[[Char]]] -> [[[Char]]]`, or even `[(Int, Char -> Bool)] -> [(Int, Char -> Bool)]`). Adding an `Eq a` constraint to make it `func :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` adds a restriction that you can only choose `a` such that `a` values can be compared for equality. When you're using a concrete type `func :: String -> String`, the caller doesn't get to choose any types, so there's no need (and no point) to add a restriction on the choice.